# A scalene triangle with no right nor obtuse angle

Tags: geometry, area

I want to find the area of the perfect triangle, *i.e.* a triangle with no particularity whatsoever :

- no side shall be equal to another,
- no right angle,
- no obtuse angle.

So I gave myself a segment $[A,B]$ of length $x$ and I drew all the lines and circles which would provide the perfect triangle from happening.

[image]

Now I want to put the point $C$ to complete the triangle in one of the two spots $C1$ or $C2$, so he is as far as possible of the forbidden lines and circles.

Remark : I don't want to put it too far north, to avoid the triangle looking particular.

I am trying to calculate the areas of the triangles $ABC1$ and $ABC2$.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: What quantities are supposed to be known?

Comment: Or by chance do you mean that circles $C1$ and $C2$ are tangent to some other lines and circles?

Comment: We know $x$, the length of $[A,B]$ @Aretino

Comment: That's what I meant @Aretino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For circle 1 (see picture below), if $r$ is the radius of the small circle and $AB=x$, from Pythagoras' theorem applied to triangles $AC_1H_1$ and $BC_1H_1$ we have:
$$
\overline{C_1H_1}^2=(x-r)^2-r^2=(x+r)^2-(x-r)^2.
$$
Solving we get $r=x/6$ and $\overline{C_1H_1}=\sqrt{2/3}x$, so the area of triangle $ABC_1$ is $\sqrt{1/6}\,x^2$.

[image]

A similar reasoning can be made for circle 2, leading to a radius $r=x/8$ and an area of $\sqrt{6}\,x^2/8$.

Comment: There was an error in my result for circle 2, which I corrected.